# How to combine Cognito User Pools with external providers like Facebook?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

So far Cognito has identity pools that support external providers like Facebook.

Now there is Cognito User Pools - which I would love to use.

But I can't figure out how to support both - Cognito User Pools and external providers like Facebook.

It seems Identity Pools and User Pools are separated things and I can't see how to put them together.

So in short, I want my users to be able to either sign in with Facebook or User Pools.

Anybody has any idea if it is even possible?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can add your Cognito User Pool as an Identity Provider in your Cognito Federated Identity Pool.

Steps:

(1) Create your user pool, note down your User Pool Id and App Client Id
(2) Navigate to the Cognito Federated Identity console.
(3) When Creating/Editing a Federated Identity Pool, expand "Authentication providers"
(4) Click the Cognito Tab
(5) Enter User Pool Id and App Client Id.

Then you will use Cognito User Pools just like you would use Amazon, Facebook, Google, Twitter, or any OIDC provider.

This blog post should help: http://mobile.awsblog.com/post/TxGNH1AUKDRZDH/Announcing-Your-User-Pools-in-Amazon-Cognito