# CODE UPDATE: AWS Cognito user identitiy pool authorization? Objective -C

Tags: objective-c, amazon-web-services, react-native, amazon-cognito

So I have been trying to figure this out and the documentation just isn't clear enough.

I am trying to use AWS cognito user pools and federated identity pools.

Online they say you can connect the two then authenticate users via your user pools to gain credentials from your identity pool.  Right now I have them connected and it's showing up as an authorization method but I am unable to figure out what to do in objective-c to get it to work.  I can only get unauthorized users into my Federated identity pool not authorized users.

I also have everything working on the user pools (creating and authenticating users) So it's just getting them into the Federated identity pool for permissions.

Could someone post a code example in objective-c on how to do it? Or walk me through the logical steps on how to do it?

I've been looking at these links:
http://mobile.awsblog.com/post/TxGNH1AUKDRZDH/Announcing-Your-User-Pools-in-Amazon-Cognito

[How to combine Cognito User Pools with external providers like Facebook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36780994/how-to-combine-cognito-user-pools-with-external-providers-like-facebook)

and just about every other aws link

An Update to the question here is some code:

I am able to sign up and verify a user however it does not register on the console in the user federated identity pool only unauthenticated. Is it a problem with my AWSServiceConfiguration? (Etc)

This is the sign up method we use to create a user

```
RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(submitUser: (NSString*) email and:

                         (NSString*) gender and:

                         (NSString*) name and:

                         (NSString*) nickname and:

                         (NSString*) picture and:

                         (NSString*) phone_number and:

                         (NSString*) preferred_username and:

                         (NSString*) hashedPass and:

                         (RCTResponseSenderBlock)callback){



  AWSCognitoIdentityUserPool *pool = [AWSCognitoIdentityUserPool CognitoIdentityUserPoolForKey:@"UserPool"];





  NSMutableArray * attributes = [NSMutableArray new];

  AWSCognitoIdentityUserAttributeType * userEmail = [AWSCognitoIdentityUserAttributeType new];

  userEmail.name = @"email";

  userEmail.value = email;

  AWSCognitoIdentityUserAttributeType * userGender = [AWSCognitoIdentityUserAttributeType new];

  userGender.name = @"gender";

  userGender.value = gender;

  AWSCognitoIdentityUserAttributeType * userName = [AWSCognitoIdentityUserAttributeType new];

  userName.name = @"name";

  userName.value = name;

  AWSCognitoIdentityUserAttributeType * userNickname = [AWSCognitoIdentityUserAttributeType new];

  userNickname.name = @"nickname";

  userNickname.value = nickname;

  AWSCognitoIdentityUserAttributeType * userPicture = [AWSCognitoIdentityUserAttributeType new];

  userPicture.name = @"picture";

  userPicture.value = picture;

  AWSCognitoIdentityUserAttributeType * userPhone = [AWSCognitoIdentityUserAttributeType new];

  userPhone.name = @"phone_number";

  userPhone.value = phone_number;

  AWSCognitoIdentityUserAttributeType * userPreferredUsername = [AWSCognitoIdentityUserAttributeType new];

  userPreferredUsername.name = @"preferred_username";

  userPreferredUsername.value = preferred_username;



  [attributes addObject:userEmail];

  [attributes addObject:userGender];

  [attributes addObject:userName];

  [attributes addObject:userNickname];

  [attributes addObject:userPicture];

  [attributes addObject:userPhone];

  [attributes addObject:userPreferredUsername];


  NSMutableString *str = [NSMutableString string];

  [str appendString:name]; 

  [str appendString:name];

  NSString *immutableString = str;  // Change later to unique identifier


  [[pool signUp:immutableString password:hashedPass userAttributes:attributes validationData:nil]

   continueWithBlock:^id(AWSTask<AWSCognitoIdentityUser*> *task) {

    if (task.error) {

      RCTLog(@"Error: %@", task.error);

    }

    if (task.exception) {

      RCTLog(@"Exception: %@", task.exception);

    }

    if (task.result) {

      RCTLog(@"Successfully registered user: %@",task.result);

    }

    callback(@[[NSNull null],@NO]);

    return nil;  

      }];

}
```

Verify User with emailed code method

```
RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(verifyUser:(nonnull NSString *)userName and:

                             (nonnull NSString *)code and:

                             (RCTResponseSenderBlock)callback) {



  AWSCognitoIdentityUserPool *pool = [AWSCognitoIdentityUserPool CognitoIdentityUserPoolForKey:@"UserPool"];

  AWSCognitoIdentityUser * user = [pool getUser:userName];




  [[user confirmSignUp:code] continueWithBlock:^id(AWSTask<AWSCognitoIdentityProviderConfirmSignUpResponse*> *task) {

    bool pass = NO;    

    if(task.error){

       RCTLog(@"Error: %@", task.error);

    }

    else if(task.exception){

       RCTLog(@"Exception: %@", task.exception);

    }

    else{

       RCTLog(@"Successfully confirmed user: %@",user.username); pass = YES;

    }

    // Return TRUE If Succead

    if(pass){

      callback(@[[NSNull null],@YES]);

    }

    else{

      callback(@[[NSNull null],@NO]);

    }

    return nil;

  }];


}
```

In Appdelegate.m

```
AWSServiceConfiguration *serviceConfiguration = [[AWSServiceConfiguration alloc] initWithRegion:AWSRegionUSEast1 credentialsProvider:nil];

  AWSCognitoIdentityUserPoolConfiguration *configuration = [[AWSCognitoIdentityUserPoolConfiguration alloc]

                                                            initWithClientId:@"clientidhere"

                                                            clientSecret:@"clientsecrethere"

                                                            poolId:@"poolidhere"];



  [AWSCognitoIdentityUserPool registerCognitoIdentityUserPoolWithConfiguration:serviceConfiguration userPoolConfiguration:configuration forKey:@"UserPool"];



  AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider *credentialsProvider = [[AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider alloc]

                                                        initWithRegionType:AWSRegionUSEast1

                                                        identityPoolId:@"identitypoolIDhere"];







  AWSServiceConfiguration *config = [[AWSServiceConfiguration alloc] initWithRegion:AWSRegionUSEast1 credentialsProvider:credentialsProvider];

  [AWSServiceManager defaultServiceManager].defaultServiceConfiguration = config;



  [AWSSQS registerSQSWithConfiguration:config forKey:@"USWest2SQS"]; // Needed for sqs work throughout the app
```

Comment: How did you connect your user pool to your federated identity pool?  Did you supply it as the identityProviderManager like the blog post?  Or did you implement your own identityProviderManager?  Be sure to call clearCredentials each time you switch users: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSiOSSDK/latest/Classes/AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider.html#//api/name/clearCredentials

Comment: behrooziAWS please see updated code.  Sorry for the delay.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by providing a CustomIdentityProvider

```
@interface CustomIdentityProvider : NSObject <AWSIdentityProviderManager>
  @property (nonatomic, retain) NSDictionary *tokens;
  - (AWSTask *) logins;
@end

@implementation CustomIdentityProvider

- (AWSTask *) logins {
    AWSTask *task = nil;

    if (nil != self.tokens) {
        return [AWSTask taskWithResult:self.tokens];
    }

    return task;
}

@end
```

When you create your AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider you need to assign the identityProviderManager

```
self.identityProviderManager = [[CustomIdentityProvider alloc] init];

self.credentialsProvider = [[AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider alloc]
                            initWithRegionType:AWSRegionUSEast1
                            identityPoolId:self.identityPoolId
                             identityProviderManager:self.identityProviderManager];
```

Once you have this set up, you need to populate the tokens NSDictionary.   This is done after calling getSession and obtaining your AWSCognitoIdentityUserSession.

```
AWSCognitoIdentityUserSession *session;  // Obtained from getSession
NSString *userPoolName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"cognito-idp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/%@", self.poolId];
NSDictionary *dict = @{userPoolName : session.idToken.tokenString};
self.customIdentityProvider.tokens = dict;
```

Assuming that you are generating your AWSAPIGatewayClient code via the SDKGeneration feature within API Gateway, you should be all set up for making your API Gateway calls as an authenticated user.

(PS.  Don't forget to configure your Federated Identity to set your IAMS role for your Authenticated users to allow execute-api:Invoke.)